# Is there any GUI framework with support for both web and desktop apps?

Tags: html, user-interface

Is there any GUI framework that can render a UI I create both as a web app and a desktop app, like on created with Qt or GTK? What I do not want is a "native" app that just displays the HTML UI in a window.

Comment: What's wrong with using a native app to display an html UI? If you want an exact match this is your best bet.

Comment: I don't want an exact match, I want both a web app and a native one that fits into the OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an effort to realize this for Qt using QML:

[QML2Web](http://gitorious.org/porting-qt-qml-to-web#more)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Silverlight if you don't mind .NET coding. It is possible to do desktop and web using the same codebase. [See example here](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/overview/out-of-browser-applications/out-of-browser-applications-%28silverlight-quickstart%29)

Comment: .NET I would mind as I don't want to develop only for Windows. Mono would be fine though. Relying on a plugin is something I'd like to avoid anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can create native apps for Linux-based OSes easily using [Quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly).

Also, in the event that you decide to just create a native app that displays HTML, note that [Prism](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/09/26/install-prism-on-linux-for-easy-to-use-web-apps/) will be a good platform to use.

It will probably save you a lot of time to just have a native app shell that displays the HTML, because there will be no extra coding.

I don't know of any programs that will convert HTML directly into native UI.